# Is there a way to produce cumulative pivots in Excel?

Tags: t-sql, excel, charts, pivot

I have some data:

```
Week Commencing       Channel      Count
----------------------------------------
 01/05/2011             C1          02
 01/05/2011             C3          01
 08/05/2011             C2          03
 15/05/2011             C1          01
```

Which produces this pivot:

```
Week Commencing       C1       C2       C3
------------------------------------------
 01/05/2011           02                01
 08/05/2011                    03
 15/05/2011           01
```

However, I would like the values to be cumulative and not to have any of the blanks:

```
Week Commencing       C1       C2       C3
------------------------------------------
 01/05/2011           02       00       01
 08/05/2011           02       03       01
 15/05/2011           03       03       01
```

This way I can create a stacked area graph over this data and show the cumulative growth of the channels.

I can see a possible solution is to "pad out" the source data so that all Channels have a row for all weeks, and also to have an additional column in the data that is the cumulative of count, per Channel, week-on-week... however, this is a fair bit of extra complexity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with a couple of CTE's, some cartesian joins and the help of a little table of numbers in master database:

```
WITH 
TestData AS (
    SELECT  CAST('01 May 2011' AS DATETIME) AS StartDate,'C1' AS Channel, 02 AS COUNT
    UNION
    SELECT  CAST('01 May 2011' AS DATETIME) AS StartDate,'C3' AS Channel, 01 AS COUNT
    UNION
    SELECT  CAST('08 May 2011' AS DATETIME) AS StartDate,'C2' AS Channel, 03 AS COUNT
    UNION
    SELECT  CAST('15 May 2011' AS DATETIME) AS StartDate,'C1' AS Channel, 01 AS COUNT
),

Data_CTE AS (
    SELECT Channel, DATEADD(d, -(DATEPART(dw, startdate)+5), CAST(startdate AS DATE)) WeekCommencing, SUM(Count) AS Count 
    FROM TestData
    GROUP BY DATEADD(d, -(DATEPART(dw, startdate)+5), CAST(startdate AS DATE)), Channel),

Sub_CTE AS (
    SELECT Dates.RefWeek, Channels.Channel, ISNULL((SELECT Count FROM Data_CTE WHERE Channel = Channels.Channel AND WeekCommencing = Dates.RefWeek) , 0) AS [Count]
    FROM
        (SELECT  DATEADD(day, number * 7, (SELECT MIN(WeekCommencing) FROM Data_CTE)) RefWeek
    FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    number
          FROM      master.dbo.spt_values
          WHERE     name IS NULL
        ) n
    WHERE   
        DATEADD(day, number * 7, (SELECT MIN(WeekCommencing) FROM Data_CTE)) <= (SELECT MAX(WeekCommencing) FROM Data_CTE)) AS Dates, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT Channel FROM Data_CTE) AS Channels)

SELECT 
    RefWeek, Channel, ( SELECT SUM(Count) FROM Sub_CTE WHERE Channel = s.Channel AND RefWeek <= s.RefWeek) 
FROM Sub_CTE s

ORDER BY s.Channel, s.RefWeek
```

Problem is that it's not really very understandable and I'm sure to wonder what the blazes I was on when I come back to look at it later :) - Oh well.